# Read data through RS232 from a device (Displacement measurement) with Python

Tags: python, serial-port

I've a displacemente measurement and I want that Python give me the values, but I do not know, How receive the data.I use this code, and give me the following error - TypeError: can't concat bytes to str.

```
`import serial

port = "COM3"
baud = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=1)

    # open the serial port
if ser.isOpen():
     print(ser.name + ' is open...')

while True:
    cmd = input("Enter command or 'exit':")
        # for Python 2
    # cmd = input("Enter command or 'exit':")
        # for Python 3
    if cmd == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii','strict')+'\r\n')
        out = ser.read()
        print('Receiving...'+out)

`
```

Answer (score 0):

`write(...` does only accept `binary`  data.

> **Documentation**  [pySerial API](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html)
>   write(data)
>   Write the bytes data to the port. This should be of type bytes (or compatible such as bytearray or memoryview). Unicode strings must be encoded (e.g.`'hello'.encode('utf-8')`.